# Data not shown o real device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-virtual-device

I'm workingon a project using react native through the Expo. If I see through the Aandroid emulator thats showing data gets from Database, everything works correctly. while if I use real device it doesn’t make me view the information, but simply everything is empty.the mode of connection I used is LAN to run my app in real device.

I've tried to turn off firewall & antivirus & my device and laptop are connecting with the same Wifi but not working.

I did a check and the data from my backend arrives correctly. What may be the problem?

May you guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: Check the logs for error

Comment: there are no error it's just empty component but in AVD that's work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by Adding base url's axios http://your add ip :8000/  instead of  http://10.0.0.1:8000/

> cmd : ipconfig